# including ChromeDriver location in my PATH environment variable broke something

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, environment-variables, robotframework

I was following [this guide](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started) for installing chrome driver. It said that I needed to include the ChromeDriver location in my PATH environment variable. I'm not a specialist so I followed this instruction to do so:

> Create directory C:\bin Download chromedriver for Windows and save to
> C:\bin Open Command Prompt and set the PATH for your account setx PATH
> "%PATH%;C:\bin" RESTART Command Prompt. Changes made by setx will only
> be picked up in new instances of Command Prompt Verify setup with
> chromedriver.exe -v

from [here](https://zwbetz.com/download-chromedriver-binary-and-add-to-your-path-for-automated-functional-testing/).

After that, i wrote `chromedriver.exe -v` as it says I should, and it works. But then I write `python` in the cmd and it returns:

```
"python" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
executable program or batch file.
```

I do the same with other technologies I have installed for example robot and the same thing.
I am a bit frustrated, I think I've broken something.

Comment: You probably messed up your environment variable, 'PATH'. You can salvage it: https://superuser.com/questions/523688/how-to-restore-the-path-environment-variable-i-deleted

Comment: What do you see if you run `echo %PATH%` in your command prompt? Do you know the location of `python.exe` in your filesystem?

Comment: I ended up fixing it by following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/523688/how-to-restore-the-path-environment-variable-i-deleted). Thank you Noah and Shane. I apologize for answering this late.